# about cutoff textview by relative layout baselines

Tags: android

I developed an android app and in which I have create relative layout and  I want to display multiple textviews but it can cutoff by vertical and horizontal baseline of relative layout

here is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:background="@drawable/single_mode_border"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.rabble.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.087"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".762"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/single_player_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.237"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/message_setting_image" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.283"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".283"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".418"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".106"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_weight=".243"
                android:src="@drawable/clock_image" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".65"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timeLeft"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".267"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Time left"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timerText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".732"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".156" >

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".843"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/currentPoint"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".315"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Current points"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".684" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight=".274"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/coin_image" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight=".118" >

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/scoreText"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_weight=".370"
                        android:background="@drawable/textview_white_rectangle_border"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:text="0" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.237" >

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".283"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.187"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".540"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".053"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight=".062"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/white_arrow"
            android:text="Button" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.884" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".460" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/fillInBlanksLinear"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".906"
            android:gravity="center" >

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/checkView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight=".093"
            android:src="@drawable/game_check_right" 
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/textrelative"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.441"
    android:layout_gravity="fill">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you have to share your XML layout

Comment: Show your xml file here

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ScrollView at the root level.Get more information from here.

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html
```

Also I see that you have got a lot of linear layouts .They should be clubbed together into lesser number of RelativeLayouts.

Comment: This must be comment!! Not accept as answer. You can modify answer of OP's question or make your answer better.

Comment: Explain what you mean by this "You can modify answer of OP's question"

Comment: What do you mean? Your answer not acceptable just giving link of developer site. Put your answer through XML file or give hint to how to change layout file using some properties.

Comment: I wanted to know how I can modify answer of OP's question. If you can help me with that.